# Cannot click a button because Selenium is unable to locate an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.8

I have tried to make my script click the Purchase/Buy Family button on the [Spotify Checkout Page](https://www.spotify.com/us/purchase/offer/family-1m-trial/?country=us). No matter what class, CSS, XPath, ID, or whatever I put in, it's just saying it could not find the object.

This is the button. It's not in an iframe:

```html
<div class="sc-fzXfOu cvoJMt">
    <button id="checkout_submit" class="Button-oyfj48-0 kaOWUo sc-fzXfOv tSdMK">
        Buy Premium Family
    </button>
</div>
```

My code:

```
time.sleep(3)
buy = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/button").click()
```

Comment: Are you sure the page is loading properly? I mean you aren't coming across any captcha or something, right?

Comment: no nothing it just cant locate the element thats all& yes the page loads properly i add a time sleep of 5 seconds and also i can send keys in the other elements its just that i cant locate that button element

Comment: The link goes to a login so I can't verify the xpath.  When you put that xpath in devtools are you certain it finds a match? - be aware of resizing the window as dyanmic pages can modify xpaths.  Are there iframes present? is 5 seconds enough to load the page?  - If you can share your DOM as text someone will most likely be ale to provide a shorter more accurate xpath

Comment: Hmm edward when i did driver.maximize_window() its giving me other location errors in my code hmm i think it has to do with the window size as u said anyway how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to click the button,by a different xpath
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='checkout_submit']")).click();

Edit -
Your xpath also works for me only when i load the page initially and there is no change in the dom - `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/button`
It doesn't work when some new event or error is displayed  and the dom structure changes.

Why use such relative XPath when the element has distinguishable attributes?

Comment: Ayu I Also Tried The Same Xpath As Urs Still Couldnt Find It :/

Comment: Okay, can you try explicit waits? WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(yourElement));

Comment: buy = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( 
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "checkout_submit")) 
    ) 
buy.click();   I Did That Ayu But Then It Says Select Object Not Callable

Comment: i fixed the select error but now it says timeout execption

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BY.ID, 'checkout_submit'))
TypeError: 'Select' object is not callable

Comment: maybe can u send a code to click that button in py?? and check if it works for u

Comment: when i remove the select module and like remove webdriver wait i get a no element exception unable to locate element error :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the form is not static you have to wait loading of all elements.

And page loads with pane to accept cookies who can mask elements you want to run action on.

The best way in that case is first accept cookies and then run all actions you need.

Try to adapt this code for your needs, that run with success on my test.

In case you run this code you have to brake execution to login first, when the driver get the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

# change this line
path_driver = "your_path_to_chrome_driver"

by, buy_selector, cookies_selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#checkout_submit', "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver)
driver.maximize_window()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/us/purchase/offer/premium-family/?country=US")


# wait for loading buy button
sls = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, buy_selector)))
if sls:
    # get accept cookies button element and click
    cookies_accept = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cookies_selector)
    if isinstance(cookies_accept, WebElement):
        cookies_accept.click()
        
    # get buy button element, move to element and click
    buy = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(buy_selector)
    if isinstance(buy, WebElement) and buy.is_displayed() and buy.is_enabled():
        actions.move_to_element(buy).click(buy).perform()
```

Comment: if the element couldnt be found how can i perform action chains on it?

Comment: the cookie selector is not being located?

Comment: i removed the cookies and now it works but when i input ur code into mine it gives me a select is not callable and i cant remove select module because its important and this is the error i get ``` sls = wait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, buy_selector)))
TypeError: 'Select' object is not callable

Comment: anyway i can fix this>>??

Comment: the clicking button worked in a seperate file where i didnt import select

Comment: it seem you have an error in your code can you post it? buy_selector is correct in your code (the selector of button is named buy above)? when you run your code it's better use editor (egg Visual Studio code) and add breakpoints, step by step to understand what happening.

Comment: i did as u did and its showing me pylint varible not callable and says Select Object Not Callable

Comment: What variable? it's seem you not initialize `buy_selector` or `by` variable. And remember, If you execute this code it's necessary break it after `driver.get(...)`, because you need login before executing the second part of code... When driver get url you are redirected to login page, you can't access directly to this url.

Comment: i entered the login url and all and then it goes to checkout and then when i use ur code it works but then when i need to enter the code where it fills the info it gives me a select is not callable error in the end of clicking it